# How to count and sum the occurrences in each column of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sum, transpose, counting

I want to try to calculate the total occurrences for each "column of digits" in the following list of numbers.

```
8353
1619
6889
3850
7596
9594
2557
8838
6224
7075
```

My expected result for the first digits is:

```
array (
    8 => 2,  // 1st and 8th number starts with 8
    1 => 1,  // 2nd number
    6 => 2,  // 3rd and 9th
    3 => 1,  // 4th
    7 => 2,  // 5th and 10th
    9 => 1,  // 6th
    2 => 1,  // 7th
)
```

I need the same kind of calculation for the other columns (2nd digits, 3rd digits, 4th digits) all collected into a multi-dimensional array.

What I did so far was like this

```
while($rowny = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mulai)) {
    $rowData[] = $rowny;
}
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    $hasil[] = $rowData[$i]['result'];

    $pecah = str_split($hasil[$i],1);
    $hitunga = array_count_values($pecah);

    print_r($hitunga);echo "<br/>";
}
```

So far when I print the `$hitunga`, it shows the array like this

```
Array ( [8] => 1 [3] => 2 [5] => 1 )
Array ( [1] => 2 [6] => 1 [9] => 1 )
Array ( [6] => 1 [8] => 2 [9] => 1 )
Array ( [3] => 1 [8] => 1 [5] => 1 [0] => 1 )
Array ( [7] => 1 [5] => 1 [9] => 1 [6] => 1 )
Array ( [9] => 2 [5] => 1 [4] => 1 )
Array ( [2] => 1 [5] => 2 [7] => 1 )
Array ( [8] => 3 [3] => 1 )
Array ( [6] => 1 [2] => 2 [4] => 1 )
Array ( [7] => 2 [0] => 1 [5] => 1 )
```

but this is changing the order of the digits and in some cases there are no numbers in the latter columns.  I expect to maintain 4 columns of numbers and get the total occurrences in each column.

Comment: Im already attach the image sir hope u cant help, on the image on every first number I want to get the total if number 8 = count, 6 = count so I can put it into graph

Comment: I don't understand your question and what you're trying to do. Maybe if you provide a better example it can help.

Comment: The current result looks the same as the image. Should "row" 1 only have 1 reference of `8` and its count be `4`?

Comment: You can use [`reset()`](https://www.php.net/reset) to get the first element of an associated array, without knowing the key.

Comment: @erendalakson, please add the actual result (values) for the mentioned array. It's hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split each number into a 4-element array.
   (`array_map('str_split', $numbers)`)
2. Transpose the new multi-dimensional structure, IOW -- convert columns to rows.
   (`array_map(null, ...#1)`)
3. Count the values.
   (`array_map('array_count_values', #2)`

One-liner:

```
array_map('array_count_values', array_map(null, ...array_map('str_split', $numbers)))
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M9nnZ))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        'array_count_values',
        array_map(
            null,
            ...array_map(
                'str_split',
                $numbers
            )
        )
    )
);
```

---

Or if you prefer language constructs, this might be easier to comprehend...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P2lnG))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    foreach (str_split($number) as $index => $digit) {
        $result[$index][$digit] = ($result[$index][$digit] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output (from both snippets):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    8 => 2,
    1 => 1,
    6 => 2,
    3 => 1,
    7 => 2,
    9 => 1,
    2 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    3 => 1,
    6 => 1,
    8 => 3,
    5 => 3,
    2 => 1,
    0 => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    5 => 3,
    1 => 1,
    8 => 1,
    9 => 2,
    3 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    7 => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    3 => 1,
    9 => 2,
    0 => 1,
    6 => 1,
    4 => 2,
    7 => 1,
    8 => 1,
    5 => 1,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Significantly less elegant and sophisticated, but this might be logic you're looking for?

```
<?php
$arr = [
    8353, 1619, 6889,3850, 7596, 9594, 2557, 8838, 6224, 7075,
];

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $split = str_split($val);
    $count[] = array_count_values($split);
}

foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    $cleanCount[] = array_values($value);
}

// careful - numbers in table must be equal length
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($arr[0]); $i++) {
    $result[$i] = array_sum(array_column($cleanCount, $i));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output (sum of count for each column):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 14
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 2
)
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/bWTvV)

Comment: I don't  see how this is valuable to the OP.  You are summing the `count` of values based on the order of the `array_count_values()` data. In other words, it looks like you ran with the OP's code that was going in the wrong logical direction. Please re-read the question.